# How can i prepopulate a text area with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I want to preset a textarea with a value but it isn't working.

```
<%= f.text_area(:self_summary, :input_html => { "date-pre" => "I will get to this later."}, :class => "textareastyle") %>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<%= f.text_area(:self_summary, :value => "I will get to this later.", :class => "textareastyle") %>
```

Comment: Wow. Somehow the more advanced stuff is less time consuming than the basics.